# Event code: 3005 Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred while attaching excel

Tags: asp.net, openxml

I have an application written in C#. In this application, i will dynamically create an excel on server and Write the List in to an excel and attach this excel in Email and send this excel to Users.

Recently, i observed that Mails are not going to Users if the List count has more than 20,000.

if the list count is Less than 20,000 then Email gets triggered successfully.

I am using DocumentFormat.Openxml.dll

When i check Event logs i saw below error

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 6/11/2013 5:29:52 PM 
Event time (UTC): 6/11/2013 9:29:52 PM 
Event ID: 74a095c641ac424cb7b00f900028bc59 
Event sequence: 50 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: XXXXXX
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path:XXXXX
    Application Path: XXXXXXXX
    Machine name: XXXXXXX

Process information: 
    Process ID: 15352 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

Request information: 
    Request URL: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    Request path: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    User host address: XXXXXXXXXX
    User: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Forms 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 1 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at btnSendNotification_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Custom event details: 

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Comment: What kind of an Excel file are u generating? What format?

Comment: The Format will be .xlsx

Comment: Could u also add to your post a part of code that throws the exception?

Comment: I am not seeing any error while debugging. But error get logs in event viewer

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.office2010.excel.slicer%28v=office.14%29.aspx) when Slicer class is used, columnCount should be less or equal 20000. That's a built-in limitation.

Comment: But we did not use Slicer class for this.

Comment: Perhaps it is used internally. Just to confirm by `list count is Less than 20,000` you do mean column count in Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: the count i was telling is Rows.

Comment: Do you think the System is timing out before the excel is written ?? Do you think due to time out, Null exception occurs. I also forgot to mention, i have this List stored in ViewState

Comment: How long does it take to export 20,000?

Comment: i am not sure but i can tell, when i tried to export 54000 now, system took about 5 to 7 mins to show me error in Even viewer log.